# Jordan Measurability of compact sets of countable size

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, compactness

In exploring situations in which Jordan Measurability is preserved under countable union I have ended up with the following question:

**Question:** Is a compact set $K \in \mathbb{R}^n$ of countable size Jordan Measurable?(or equivalently a compact set with countably many limit points).

In the case of finitely many limit points the answer is yes and measure is $0$. (Clearly any Jordan measure set of countable size must have measure $0$) We can see this by surrounding the finitely many limit points with rectangles and that takes care of co-finite points however small the rectangles might be.

Now with examples of compact sets with countably infinite limit points that I could construct the answer is again yes. For example $\{0 \}\ \cup \{ \frac{1}{n} \} \cup \{ \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{m} \}$. Here a rectangle around $0$ takes care of cofinitely many of the other limit points. So, we are left with finitely many limit points (of the form $\frac{1}{n}$). So, again $0$.

This example can be generalized as:

If $A$ is countable.

Now, if I can partition $A$ into a 'heirarchy based on limit points' as:

$A = A_1 \cup A_2 \cdots A_n$ where each $A_i$ is discrete on its own(every point of $A_i$ is isolated in $A_i$ ) and every point of $A_{i+1}$ is a limit point of $A_i$ and $A_n$ is finite then  $A$ is Jordan Measurable.

Apart from this I haven't made progress.

Comment: The answer is Yes. In fact it is easy to see that outer Jordan measure and outer Lebesgue measure will always be same for any compact set.

Comment: In fact with the above observation and using the continuity of Lebesgue measure one can show that if an increasing chain of Jordan measurable compact sets increases to a compact set then this compact set is also Jordan measurable.